# Python Socket programming on Linux - Errno 19 : No such device

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I've got a little problem. While debugging this code:

```
s=socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP)
try:
    host=gethostbyname(gethostname())
    s.bind((host, 0))

    subprocess.check_call(['ifconfig', 'eth0', 'promisc'])
```

I get an Error `[Errno 19] No such device`, while line `s.bind((host, 0))` is called.

Comment: code returns `host = 127.0.1.1`. (shouldn't it be 127.0.0.1 ?)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using raw sockets, the argument to `bind` should be adjusted accordingly. See the following snippet from the hep for `socket.bind`

```
bind(...) unbound socket._socketobject method
bind(address)

Bind the socket to a local address.  For IP sockets, the address is a
pair (host, port); the host must refer to the local host. For raw packet
sockets the address is a tuple (ifname, proto [,pkttype [,hatype]])
```

I'm guessing `s.bind(('eth0', N))` should work for you. You need to read up on how to select the correct value for N.

Comment: that `s.bind((host, 0))` is from python docs, and code of simple sniffer for windows (`# create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
s.bind((HOST, 0))`).
Can you explain something more about this difference in `s.bind()` because I cannot found anything about that ?

Comment: Do you mean : s.bind(('eth0', 0x0800)) ?